# “Se servir de (carrière)” peut être suivi d’articles ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot

Normalement, on écrit « je suis un médecin compétent » et « je suis médecin »
donc est-ce qu’on peut faire la même chose sur « se servir de »?

Par exemple ; je me sers de médecin
; je me sers d’un médecin compétent

Comment: "Je me sers de médecin" n'est pas correct en français, et "je me sers d'un médecin compétent" non plus. Le verbe habituel pour aller chez un médecin est consulter : Je vais consulter un médecin compétent.

Answer (score 2):

*Je me sers de médecin* voudrait plutôt dire *Je suis mon propre médecin*.
*Je me sers d'un médecin compétent* n'est pas très idiomatique, on dirait plutôt *Je consulte un médecin compétent* ou encore *Je vais voir un médecin compétent*.